# Sum of two distance distribution functions

Tags: normal-distribution

I have two rough surfaces A and B, each with standard height deviation $\sigma _a$ and $\sigma _b$ and mean height $z_a$ and $z_b$.

[image]

Now my question is:

**How can I find a distance distribution between the two surfaces ?**

I know that both surfaces can be modeled as Gaussian:

$$h(z) = \frac{1}{{\sigma \sqrt {2\pi } }}e^{{{ - \left( {z- \mu } \right)^2 } \mathord{\left/ {\vphantom {{ - \left( {z - \mu } \right)^2 } {2\sigma ^2 }}} \right.-} {2\sigma ^2 }}}$$

So to find the distance between the surfaces, can I just sum them, like so ?

$$h_a(z) + h_b(z)$$

Answer (score 2):

Let the two profiles be denoted by $y_a(i)$ and $y_b(i)$. As they both come from a Gaussian distribution, the difference is also Gaussian (e.g., see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables)).
Thus, if $y_a(i) \sim N(z_a, \sigma_a^2)$ and $y_b(i) \sim N(z_b, \sigma_b^2)$ with
$$
N(z,\sigma) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{(y-z)^2}{2\sigma^2}},
$$
then the difference is $(y_a(i)-y_b(i)) \sim N(z_a-z_b, \sigma_a^2+\sigma_b^2)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Why would you take the difference and not the sum ?

Comment: You are interested in the distance. I interpreted the "distance" as being the difference between two numbers (but correct me if this isn't what you are looking for)

Comment: @james If you are interested in a signed distance (so negative if b < a and positive if the other way around)  you should take the difference. If you want to have an absolute distance take the absolute distance of the difference, hence $|y_a - y_b|$ then you get a (shifted) [half-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution)

Comment: @Gono Thank you very much for your clarification ! When you look at the picture, which distance would you choose ?

Comment: It really depends if you want to have a signed difference or not. Easier for calculation is the signed one… the absolute one is more "natural". E.g. you won't note the distance from your home to school as "-10km" if you measure it from school instead from home.… do you?